# How do I select an empty key in JSON?

Tags: json

I have some JSON I'm trying to parse. I don't know if this is considered malformed, but a key is empty:

```
{"value": ["", {"Fields":...}]}
```

I want to get to the "Fields" element, but I can't get past the empty string. I've tried:

```
JSON.parse(results).value.@"".Fields
```

but that returns an error "No such field: *empty* for class org.codehaus.groovy.grials.web.json.JSONArray.

How can I access "Fields", or is this just bad json?

Comment: Did you actually read JSON's specs? It doesn't seem so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a key, it's an element in an array. Note the difference between the braces. Simply access the element at index 1 of the array under `value`.

Comment: Ah, you mean accessing what's supposedly a value for this key…

Answer (score 2):

`value` is an array.
`value[0]` is the empty string.
`value[1]` is an object.